# Display stdout as Received in Emacs Shell-Mode

Tags: shell, emacs

Is there any way to get Emacs Shell-Mode to display output as it receives it instead waiting for the previous command to finish?

For example:

```
python -c "import time; print  'hello'; time.sleep(3); print '...goodbye'"
```

Will pause for 3 seconds and then print "hello" and "...goodbye" at the same time. I'm trying to get it to print "hello", wait three seconds, and then print "...goodbye".

I'm running Emacs 25.0.93.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what's happening is that the "hello" is stuck in the output buffer and doesn't get output until the program exits (or the buffer fills up more).  This also happened when I ran your code in a bash console window (outside of emacs).

You can manually flush the output buffer using `sys.stdout.flush()`, which will cause the text in the buffer ("hello") to be displayed immediately.

I tested the following code in emacs's shell, eshell, and term modes (note I also converted the print statements to python3 syntax):

```
python -c "import time; import sys; print ('hello'); sys.stdout.flush(); time.sleep(3); print ('...goodbye')"
```